# how i can attach only one file using ng2FileSelect

Tags: angular

I want to attach only one file using ng2FileSelect in angular 4 
my code are as follows:
enclosures: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
      url: URL,
      isHTML5: true
    });

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you tell us what you expected to happen, and what actually happened when you ran this code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict it to one file you can use something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.uploader =  = new FileUploader({
    url: URL
});
this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = f => {
    if (this.uploader.queue.length > 1) {
        this.uploader.removeFromQueue(this.uploader.queue[0]);
    }
  };
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is could be in the html. if you have

`<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple  />`

remove **multiple** to only allow a single file upload.

`<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />`